# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Verifying channel response identity](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17292/verifying-channel-response-identity)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Count objects in the image](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17328/count-objects-in-the-image)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Difficulties in understanding mutual information concept](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17514/difficulties-in-understanding-mutual-information-concept)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [FFT Matlab - Meaning of Frequency Vector](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17537/fft-matlab-meaning-of-frequency-vector)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Filtering a Morse code (CW, OOK) signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17439/filtering-a-morse-code-cw-ook-signal)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Maximum Likelihood through a noisy channel](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17310/maximum-likelihood-through-a-noisy-channel)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to model Tape Saturation (Audio DSP)?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17526/how-to-model-tape-saturation-audio-dsp)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Conceptual question on entropy and its relation to information](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17498/conceptual-question-on-entropy-and-its-relation-to-information)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Time-frequency synchronization algorithm for OFDM continuous stream](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17470/time-frequency-synchronization-algorithm-for-ofdm-continuous-stream)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Calculating the Power spectral density](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17302/calculating-the-power-spectral-density)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 6)

---